# Информация по работе с регулярными выражениями?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Гуглил никак не могу найти норм ресурсов по которым можно их изучить, 90% инфы что я находил это уже готовые регулярки. Так же находил книгу Дж. Фридла, но как-то не хочется по этой теме читать такую толстую книгу.

Comment: **Читайте книгу**.  Конструкторы, вики - бред. Ими можете пользоваться в том случае, если Вы не хотите понимать как работают регулярные выражения. Ставлю всем ответам минус кроме того, который не порекомендовал конструктор, а дал ссылку непонятно на что- хоть что-то на фоне двух других ответов.  
П.С. Сам читал Фридла и частенько прокачиваю свои навыки в владении регексами отвечая на вопросы здесь, которые зачастую гораздо проще решить уже готовыми парсерами, и Вам советую делать также предварительно прочитав книгу, иначе будете пытаться составить выражения даже не понимая как они работают.

Comment: Согласен. Либо читаешь нормальную книгу, либо вопрос вообще снимается - так толком ничему не научишься.

Comment: @ReinRaus нравится вам учиться по книгам - так порекомендуйте книги :) Насчет приведенного мною конструктора, смысл в нем - можно сохранять регулярки с данными и постить их на форуме, в качестве примера. Кому-то нужны книги для того чтобы овладеть предметом, а кому-то достаточно справочника и инструмента для оттачивания навыков. Теоретиков и практиков еще никто не отменял :)

Comment: А книга всего одна - упоминаемый Фридл, она же "Mastering Regular Expressions".

Comment: @vv2cc конструкторы никогда не создадут выражение со сложностью «чуть выше примитивного». Также прочитав Вики Вы никогда не поймете разницу между выражениями:  

    .*(текст.*?)$
    (текст.*?)$
Ведь они делают итого и тоже, ага.  
@klopp есть еще книга дракона, но ее вроде нет нормального перевода, а в английском я не силен, поэтому не читал.

Comment: @ReinRaus Исправился. Добавил перечень "Азы". А в целом, я с Вами согласен - учиться необходимо на собственной практике.

Comment: Кхм, для начала стоит просто выучить синтаксис, дальше набивать руку. Было бы не плохо также обсуждать свою версию регулярки и версию других пользователей на форуме, дабы увидеть, как можно проще и эффективней сделать выражение.

Comment: Кому-то нужна пушка, чтобы стрелять по воробьям, а кому-то достаточно рогатки там, где нет необходимости в пушке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имхо, этого достаточно: [Регулярные выражения](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) + [Конструктор регулярных выражений](http://www.pcre.ru/eval/)

Comment: Удобный конструктор, на мой взгляд: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1):

Вот, [**посмотрите**](http://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction)... Подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

Азы:

[wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[менее запутано](http://valex.net.ru/regexp.html)

[про модификаторы](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Примеры:

[regexlib.ru](http://regexlib.ru/)

[Множество примеров](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Regulyarnye_vyrazheniya_dlya_chaynikov.html)

[Регулярные выражения для продвинутых пользователей](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=920)

**+** любой конструктор. [[@vv2cc](/users/7163/vv2cc)](/users/7163/vv2cc) один из таких привёл.